# Change label text of Ladda Bootstrap button while loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am using Ladda Bootstrap. What I am trying to achieve is pretty obvious and straight forward.

I want to change the text of Button when I click on the button. How can I do that?

[Example](http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/)

Comment: Maybe you can bind an onClick event to the button and change it's text there and once the loading is finished (maybe check for the spinner if it has already disappeared), you can rever the text back.

Comment: Well i can do that, but i was looking for a way that Lada helps me do that. I thought i might be missing some point?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, This is also pretty simple. 
There is no way you can do it in current version, but maybe they enable in the upcoming versions.

### Here is the code.

```
btnSelector = $(".my-ladda-btn");
var yourButton = Ladda.create(btnSelector);
yourButton.start();
btnTextSelector = btnSelector.find('.ladda-label');
currnetText = btnTextSelector.text()
btnTextSelector.text('Loading..');
```

when you want to `stop` the button.

```
btnTextSelector.text(currentText);
yourButton.stop();
```

pretty simple right?

Comment: Dont work. Firefox says: TypeError: t.querySelector is not a function. Tested with jQuery 1.9

Comment: This answer contains broken code. When using jQuery for selecting the button DOM element, you need to access the zeroth element: `$('.btn')[0]`. This is the native DOM element, not a jQuery object (and the `create` method requires a native DOM element).

Comment: From my testing, you must also change the text after the start(), and change it back before the .stop(). Do it the other way around and you'll get the text doubled up

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke You're absolutely right! Thanks!